# Multipolygon in DSE Graphs

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup, datastax-enterprise-graph

I need to store Multipolygon data in Datastax Graph. They do support some of geo data types like point, line String and polygon . Do they support Multipolygon.

Could you please help with this

Answer (score 3):

DSE Graph does not support explicit Multipolygon data types.

If you don't mind sharing, what types of issues/challenges does Multipolygon help you solve?

Comment: Well, I have couple of use cases which are supported by geospatial searches like getting all the cities or regions within 10 km range or with some degree.

Comment: In these use cases, it sounds as if the cities are polygons while the range outside of these cities creates the surrounding polygon, therefore you're looking to use multipolygon?  Is this accurate?  Is this the type of problem you're trying to solve with multipolygon?

Comment: Actually we are having multi polygon because we are having state with lot of islands. so each polygon represent a island.

Comment: Also, I have to solve two problems point in polygon.. Like from current lat and long which polygon I belong. The other is time/distance driven polygon, from my current position in some x km distance or x min till which all polygons I can visit.

Comment: Adding my answer as a comment, as I have this ban on answers. Not sure what it is and how it works. Not want to leave question answered. here is the answer.    As of now DSE 6.7 it does not support Multipolygons and all sort of Spatial queries on it. The only way to store multipolygons and run spatial queries is via Solr and JTS library.

set up JTS lib in DSE create a Solr indexing on Multipolygon data and point the datatype to JTS type data type.

I tried it and it worked like charm!!